# How to remove a String with an regex?

Tags: java, regex

i'm sorry for the unclear title, but i don't know how to call it.
its easier to show by a simple sample.

i have the following lines in a text file (actually its `PHP` code)

```
'config' => array
(
    'dataContainer' =>  'Table',
    'enableVersioning'  =>  true,
),
'list' => array
(
    'sorting' => array
    (
        'mode'  =>  0,
        'flag'  =>  0,
        'panelLayout'   =>  'filter;sort,search,limit',
        'fields' => array
        (
            'id',
            'guid',
            'name',
        ),
    ),
)
```

i want to replace the ',' of last lines of those arrays, to correct the output. like this:

```
'config' => array
(
    'dataContainer' =>  'Table',
    'enableVersioning'  =>  true
),
'list' => array
(
    'sorting' => array
    (
        'mode'  =>  0,
        'flag'  =>  0,
        'panelLayout'   =>  'filter;sort,search,limit',
        'fields' => array
        (
            'id',
            'guid',
            'name'
        )
    )
)
```

so my try to catch the strings was:

```
String regex = ",\n[^\\t]*[)]";
code = code.replaceAll(",\n[^\\t]*[)]", "\n");
```

which is a comma followed by a newline, a linestart with an arbitrary number of tabs and an enclosing round bracket.

this should be replaced by an newline, the arbitrary number of tabs and the enclosing round bracket,

so after all, only the comma gets stripped off.

how can i do this?

Comment: In short comma after closing bracket, right?

Comment: Should comma after `name` be also removed?

Comment: Subject is PHP code, but problem and solution is about Java code. So don't retag this question from `java` to `PHP` (people who approved [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8460748) should take long break from reviewing).

Comment: true Pshemo, this is for Java code. the content which shall get parsed by the regex is PHP code though. still the retag to php is completely wrong!    yes @Pshemo i removed the comma after name now.

Comment: @Aditya nope also comma before closing a bracket shall be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this and replace by `empty string`

```
code = code.replaceAll(",(?=\\s*\\))", "")
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but can you explain this to me? comma followed by a number of whitespaces, whereat (?=XXX) means its only for search but not replace?

Comment: @lumo `(?=xxx)` is called lookahead mechanism. It is zero-length (or zero-width as some people call it) and it is not part of the match. It just makes sure that after place where it is used `xxx` part exist. So in this case we just accept `,` which have zero or more whitespaces (`\\s*`) which have also closing parenthesis after it `\\)` (`)` needs to be escaped as one of regex metacharacters).

Comment: @lumo You can read more about it at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead

Answer (score 2):

Replace `,(\\s*\\))` with `$1`. Here `$1` means the first group captured by the regex (i.e. `\\s*\\)`, multiple whitespaces followed by a `)`).

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work. I've tried right now. It's a sad fact.

Comment: Oops, forgot to escape the `\\` s. Updated.

Comment: We need to use `$x` in replacement part not `\x` (where `x` is group index). `\x` is backreference which we can use only inside regex, like `(.)\1` will try to find two continues identical characters.

Answer (score 1):

A good replacement would be:

```
String corrected = input.replaceAll(",(\\s*\\))", "$1" );
```

- The comma character is matched with the comma
- The \s* matches with all whitespace including new line characters
- The ( ) makes a grouping: it names all spaces and you can use in your replacement putting a $1
- \) matches with a parenthesis. You have to put \) to avoid the ) which is an special character for regular expressions

Comment: "But unfortunately the replaceAll doesn't do that." What do you mean by that? We can simply use `$x` where `x` is group number to reuse part matched by that group. Example `"abcd".replaceAll("(.)(.)","$2$1")` will result in `badc`.

Comment: For named groups `(?<name>regex)` we can use `${name}` in replacement part. `"abcd".replaceAll("(?<first>.)(?<second>.)","${second}${first}")` -> `"badc"`.

Comment: "*I've reached the conclusion that you can't only remove just the comma: you have to remove all the new lines and whitespaces aswell.*" no, just because you ware not able to do something doesn't mean it can't be done. Please check accepted answer.

Comment: @Pshemo Oh!! It's a dollar.... sh*t. I thought I had to use a \ (backslash) sign. In that case, I have to correct my post.

Comment: `\groupID` is used in regex itself, for instance to find `aa` `bb` we could use `(\w)\1`. `$groupID` is used in replacement part of `replaceAll(regex, replacement)`.

Comment: @Pshemo Ok, thanks. In that case my solution is the same as 0605002's.

Comment: Yes, you had the same idea (and similar mistakes :). Anyway since your solution is corrected +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
    code = code.replaceAll(",\\s+\\)", "\n)");
```